Can I subset an Iterator and keep it an Iterator?
I have a use case where I need the permutations of boolean. However I do not need them when they are reversed. So I can do something like this:
import itertools

[
    p for p in 
    itertools.product([True,False],repeat=4)
    if p!=p[::-1]
]

This issue is that this is a list, stored in memory, and with increasing repeats I will run into memory errors.
Is it possible to "subset" an iterator while keeping it as an iterator?
If possible I am looking for a general answer, that applies to any sub setting strategy on any iterator

You use a generator expression, syntactically identical to a listcomp, but using parentheses rather than square brackets as the delimiter:
(
    p for p in 
    itertools.product([True,False],repeat=4)
    if p!=p[::-1]
)

If the generator expression is the sole argument to a function, you don't even need the extra parentheses (the function call parentheses serve double duty delimiting the function argument and the genexpr).


Is it possible to "subset" an iterator while keeping it as an
iterator?

You might itertools.filterfalse in your use case, namely
import itertools
iterator = itertools.filterfalse(lambda p:p==p[::-1],itertools.product([True,False],repeat=4))
for i in iterator:
    print(i)
next(iterator) # raise StopIteration as iterator is exhausted

gives output
(True, True, True, False)
(True, True, False, True)
(True, True, False, False)
(True, False, True, True)
(True, False, True, False)
(True, False, False, False)
(False, True, True, True)
(False, True, False, True)
(False, True, False, False)
(False, False, True, True)
(False, False, True, False)
(False, False, False, True)

Keep in mind predicate (here lambda p:p==p[::-1]) must hold for elements which you want to drop.

Two notes: 1) Bear in mind, if you need a lambda to use the existing map/filter/filterfalse, it's likely slower and less readable than the same genexpr that avoids the function call overhead. 2) In this particular case, if you're using a lambda anyway, why bother with itertools.filterfalse when you could just flip the condition and use filter without the import? filterfalse is really only useful when an existing function does exactly what you want but gets the condition backwards for filter.
